# Raspberry pi 3 stuck on bootloader

Tags: boot, kernel, boot-issues

Raspberry pi 3 is stuck in boot. When i was last using it i disabled the wlan0 for some hardware hack, after that when i rebooted it it stuck on the boot as shown below.

I have even tried to flash the memory card with other operating systems but the error remains the same
 it says

```
failed to start braille device support
failed to start load kernel modules
```

and many more

[image]

Comment: As implied by my edit, the image demonstrates it is *not* "stuck in the bootloader", since that is output from the linux kernel, i.e., the bootloader has already finished and loaded a kernel.  It looks to me like filesystem corruption is a likely explanation, you should run `fsck` on the second partition in another computer.   WRT "I have even tried to flash the memory card with other operating systems" -> If the error is more or less the same each time, then you **did not** succeed in flashing the card with anything (unless the SD card reader itself is damaged).